# How to handle parse Error or Compilation Error while doing require_once in php

Tags: php, error-handling

I am importing file using require_once. But the php file we are including is auto generated and is sometimes blank, or have parse error or compilation error, which cause script to fail. I want that script should not stop executing and should set another variable if such case is encountered. I tried try-catch but of no help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`require_once` *requires* that file. If it is acceptable for the file to be blank or non-existent or the like then you should use `include_once` instead. The return value of `include_once` can be checked to see if the include was successful:

```
$res = include_once 'foo.php';
if(!$res){
    echo "Uh-oh";
}
```

Note that this will still issue a warning if the file is not successfully included. Also not that an included file can return values into `$res` (including false).

Answer (score 0):

`require_once` does not throw an error if the file is empty, only if the file does not exist. Use [`is_readable`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-readable.php) to test whether a file exists and is readable.

```
if ( is_readable( 'file.php' ) ) require_once( 'file.php' );
else $var = false;
```